# Is it possible to disallow index of a resource with tastypie?

Tags: django, api, rest, tastypie

I want `read` to be visible on the api:

```
/api/resource/1
```

But not `index`:

```
/api/resource/
```

Is it possible with django-tastypie ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs, we can restrain index methods using [Meta.list_allowed_methods](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#list-allowed-methods):

```
class Resource(ModelResource)
    class Meta:
        list_allowed_methods = []
```

It produces a `HTTP 405: METHOD NOT ALLOWED` when trying to access `/api/v1/resource/`.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve here?

It is possible to limit the list displayed in /api/resource per user.
This can be done using something like:

```
def get_object_list(self, request):
    return super(ResourceName, self).get_object_list(request).filter(user=request.user)
```